# Twitter-bootstrap modal does not close on click

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am getting trouble with Twitter bootstrap modal. It does not close even if I click on the close button.

I have created the modal to available from the beginning i.e. on the page load it shows the modal. I did not use any javascript on my part.

Here is the code

```
<div id="myModal2" class="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel2" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
    <h3 id="myModalLabel2">Instructions</h3>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
    <ol><li>Please press either left or right arrow button to start the carousel.</li><li>For continuous movement either put the cursor on this dialog or outside the viewport</li></ol>

</div>
<div class="modal-footer"><button class="btn" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">View Source</button>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>
</div>
```

One thing, I should mentioned that I have two modal in the same page.

And if you would like to see the page live, here is the link
http://nazmulweb.com/bootstrap_carousel_full_page_fade

If you have anything need to know more, please let me know.

Thank you so much.

Comment: Try adding fade class to modal i.e `class="modal fade"`

Comment: @anpsmn if I add "fade" to the class, during the page load the modal is not visible.

Comment: I guess bootstrap expects all classes to be there modal fade in hide. You can give all the classes and show the modal through script `$('#myModal').modal('show')`.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue. I could solve it by placing dialog div at the very bottom of the page (just before closing body tag)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding hide and fade classes to the modal div. 
i.e,

```
<div id="myModal2" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel2" aria-hidden="true">
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this close button.

```
<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">×</span></button>
```